# Liquibase is not rolling back database tags

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

When I execute rollback from command line it shows successfully executed. But on database there are no changes applied. I am using PostgreSQL DB. The command I used for rollback is

```
java -jar C:\Users\Ranjith.s\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase-core\3.5.5\liquibase-core-3.5.5.jar --changeLogFile=src\main\resources\db\changelog\db.changelog-master.xml  --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/transformation_as_a_service --classpath=C:\softwares\liquibase\lib\postgresql-42.2.11.jar --username=transformation_as_a_service_admin --password=transformation_as_a_service_admin --logLevel=debug rollback version_2020.3.002
```

I am pasting changelog file for reference

```
<changeSet id="2020-03-UPDATE-PRIMARY-KEY-TO-COLUMN-PID" author="TAAS">
    <preConditions onFail="HALT">
        <columnExists tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION" columnName="PID"/>
    </preConditions>
    <dropPrimaryKey constraintName="pk_tb_transformation" tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION"/>
    <addUniqueConstraint tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION" columnNames="ID" constraintName="idx_taas_id" />
    <addPrimaryKey tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION" columnNames="PID" constraintName="idx_taas_pid"/>
    <rollback>
        <dropPrimaryKey tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION"/>
        <dropColumn tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION" columnName="PID"/>
        <addPrimaryKey tableName="TB_TRANSFORMATION" columnNames="ID" constraintName="idx_taas_id"/>
    </rollback>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="TAAS" id="tag_version_2020.3.002">
    <tagDatabase tag="version_2020.3.002" />
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is your complete changelog, and you ran `liquibase update` before running the `liquibase rollback` command, then it is working as designed. The idea is that you would run update and it would deploy those changes. You then continue on, adding more changesets and deploying them using the update command. But on one of those deployments, you discover a problem and decide that you need to go back to a know good version, so you use the rollback command with the tag, and it rolls back everything *AFTER* the tag.

Comment: Sorry for less details. Actually there is another changelog executed before this. I found the issue with rollback. It is filename which is stored in db as
** classpath:/db/changelog/snapshot-version/transformation-as-a-service.changelog.xml**
The liquibase is executed from docker image. For rollback i am using maven plugin from local. I don't know how to set classpath:/ when i run maven plugin.

Comment: In your changelogs, you can add a new attribute to the root `databaseChangeLog` element named `logicalFilePath`, and set that as needed. The issue with classpath: being added in some cases but not others is something the team is working on fixing.